# Managing water entry at garage door during high winds on rainy days

Tags: garage, waterproofing, drainage, garage-door

I have a garage floor that's level, and the driveway slopes very slightly away from the garage door.  On rainy days, I don't have any issues with water entry, but on high-wind days, the rain hits the garage door, then runs down and pools at the corners.  Eventually over time, the pool of water increases in size and makes its way into my garage.  It only happens once in a while, but when it does, it can be annoying if I happen to leave stuff by the door.

Is there a way to manage or make improvements to this with a minimal amount of work?  I don't want to have to tear out the garage floor.

Since the finished floor extends past the garage door by about 4 inches, perhaps this small section can be graded so the floor is sloped all of the way up to the door.  This would prevent pooling at the corners.  Then I could have a contractor remove the pavers in the driveway along the doors and install a trough / drain and maybe some kind of grate.

Does this sound like the most reasonable way to deal with it?  It's pouring right now, but if it helps, I can take pictures and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could simply cut/have cut drainage channels from the problem areas to the front of the slab, or do that and also have a trough drain installed along the front of the slab. I'd start with the simpler/cheaper approach first - simple job with a diamond blade and a grinder or saw.

Answer (score 0):

Before you think about drain troughs, you might consider fitting a Stormguard Garage Threshold seal on the inside of the floor. It has an upstand of about 15mm. It stopped the autumn leaves blowing in on my friend's ill fitting up and over door. Also stopped the snow blowing in. It's available from Screwfix for about £30 {code No. 37019}.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, actually.  The water just runs around it eventually.

Comment: If the water runs around it then something is wrong with the installation.  The ends of it should Touch the door jam and be sealed with silicon.  If your door sits significantly back from the jam then you could  run it past the jam and cut a 45  degree miter in the threshold and run it to the wall and then silicone everything real good.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your door shuts down onto the level of the floor, which is permitting the water to be driven underneath.

Locally modern installations of garage doors close into a reveal which is a depression under the door only, with a level about 10-25mm below that of the garage floor.  Your car/bike/wheelbarrow's wheels will simply roll up this small step exactly like they would roll over a normal stormwater drain.

Sounds like you need to talk to a local concrete cutter to take a long thin rectangular section out from your floor.  Then seal the new exposed surface well because it will be driven on and exposed to pooled water.

Do check that your door has enough "spare" height to close down another 25mm or 1 inch too.  If it doesn't then you may have to add height at the top of the door to make up the difference.