# Feedback on ideas for stopping water from coming under garage door

Tags: leak, garage

I have two garage doors that both occasionally experience water coming in. This happens on rainy days, but only when the wind is against the door. The grade is OK, except there is an inch or less of depression right in front of the door - it's like the door fits down into a groove. So water doesn't run from the ground into the garage, however water runs down the door itself, pools in the depression, and eventually gets inside. My actual problem seems similar to the one in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106096/managing-water-entry-at-garage-door-during-high-winds-on-rainy-days), however I would like to ask for review of my own remedy idea:

I would like to put something like flashing to extend a lip out along the bottom front of the garage door(s), to direct the water running down the face of the door away to the graded slope (less than an inch away).

What materials might work for this? Metal flashing is obviously a possibility (not sure I have the skills for this). Being DIY-minded, I'm thinking about experimenting with a stiff waterproof canvas - if not stiff enough, glue two layers together. I could glue a thin strip of wood or some kind of small profile moulding along the bottom of the garage door, then after it is firm, glue a strip of canvas, held tight at a 90 deg angle above and along the top of the wood strip, so it would make it stick out. Think it would work, or would I just be messing up my door?

Comment: Do you have to get cars through said garage doors?

Comment: Yes, car access is needed.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I haven't resolved it yet due to not getting around to it (and deliberately being slow due to reticence to change anything permanently / mess stuff up). That said, I think the top rated answer below is as good an option as mine. I may eventually try mine anyway, but will go ahead and select this person's as accepted. Thanks for the bump on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this idea before you mess up your doors. Cut small drainage grooves on the outside of the depression to allow the water to escape. A small kerf at either end and maybe one in the middle should be all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of that. Isn't it better to stop the water before it gets into the groove, though? I don't have leakage unless it is really raining to beat the band and the groove is filled up. Concerned that unless I cut it off from the source the problem will remain. (The source being the sheet of water coming down the door itself when it rains directly against the door.)

Comment: I think no matter how hard you try to keep water out of the trench wind will blow some back, cutting a drain sounds like the best choice to me.+

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the driveway grade is okay, then using a concrete surface grinder you can angle the edge of the garage floor slab so the slope directs water out on to the approach apron. The detail I attached isn't exactly what I'm talking about (don't make a 1-1/2" raised shoulder or add a door wedge) but the idea is that your shop floor can begin to slope towards the approach apron to direct water outside by grinding down the concrete in that area. (Sorry, also ignore the pole that is drawn on that image)

[image: Approach Apron]